# jquery prevent reload form on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to upload files using javascript/jquery/ajax and in my case, I have to prevent the reload on form submitting on upload.
Also, I want to add a delete button, such that, when file is uploaded, the delete button can delete this and same is the scenario, that to prevent the page refresh/reload on form submitting.

Hence, I've three buttons in a single form, **UPLOAD**, **DELETE**, **NEXT** and in my case, only next allows to submit the form by refreshing/action of form. And obviously, when file is just selected and the user directly hits the next button, it first uploads and then take his action.

HTML:

```
    <form name="myform" method="post" id="FORM2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
// OTHER VALUES OF FORM
                    <input type="file" name="FileUpload-1" id="FileUpload-1"  class="file_upload" />

                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload" class="submitUpload" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="delete" class="submitDelete" />


<input type="submit" name="" id="FORMSUBMIT">
</form>
```

JS:

```
  $(".submitUpload").click(function(){ console.log('UPLOAD');
        action = "upload.php"; 
         $("#FORM").on('submit',function(){
          var options={
           url     : action,
           success : onsuccess
          };
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
         return false;
         });
     }
     return false;

    });

     $(".submitDelete").click(function(){ console.log('DELETE');
        return false;
    });
 $('.FORMSUBMIT').click(function () {
         //CUSTOM HANDLING
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

To Directly answer your question:

```
$("#FORM").on('submit',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

This piece of code will prevent the normal form submitting.
My advice is to transform the Update and Delete buttons from type=submit to type=button. Like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" id="Delete" class="submitDelete" />
```

This will prevent the form to be submitted when delete or update are pressed...

I wrote a jsfiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/yL35bh10/

Comment: Let me try in my piece of code. I'll update you after checking.

Comment: I'm calling this fuction `$("#FORM2").on('submit',function(){
              var options={
               url     : "upload.php?PICTURE1=1"
              };
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

             });` But it doen't uploading as the form is not submitting.

Comment: if you listen on form submit, you have to let the "Upload" button be type="submit", otherwise you have to listen on btn click:
$(".submitUpload").on('click', function(evt) { [...] });

Comment: If I change by input type from button to submit, then it always submits the form of upload, on delete and also on next

Answer (score 0):

I recently prototyped a page needing image file upload.  I found a package on GitHub that was easy to use and should provide the majority of the functionality you're needing.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

My only question to you:  Once a file is uploaded to the server, how are you going to know what to delete?

Comment: I'm storing the file's unique name in a PHP SESSION variable.